# Error on User Role Management

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

I got this Fatal Error whenever I go to System > Permissions > Roles and Click any Role.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Magentix_Fee_Helper_Data' not found in /public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547

but I can locate this:

> /app/code/local/Magentix/Fee/Helper/Data.php

What could be the possible solution to this?

Comment: Please provide us config.xml  and adminhtml.xml code I face same problem few days ago hope I can solve yours

Comment: @murtuza it is fixed now. Thanks for taking your time to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your have module name `Magentix_Fee`.

Your issue has been created for ***wrong calling of helper class*** in **system.xml** and **adminhtml.xml** of that module `[app/code/local/Magentix/Fee/etc]`

May be your try to  add code like `module="magentix_fee"` that **those two files**.

But it should be **prefix  type of helper that module** .I Assume that  helper **prefix is [fee](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/etc/config.xml#L35) for that module**.

So you need to change `module="magentix_fee"` to `module="fee"`

Example for default magento `Phoenix_Moneybookers` the helper class prefix is [moneybrokers](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/etc/config.xml#L35)

Comment: I could see that in adminhtml.xml `<mycustom_section translate="title" module="Magentix_Fee">`. It must be small letters?

Comment: Can share code config.xml after that i tell u

Comment: I can also see all module in system.xml are `module="fee" `

Comment: It is too long @AmitBera

Comment: please put part of code  `<helper>...</helper>;

Comment: this is the code: `<helpers>
            <fee>
                <class>Magentix_Fee_Helper</class>
            </fee>
        </helpers>`

Comment: aha. module="Magentix_Fee" should be module="fee"

Comment: on the adminhtml.xml @AmitBera

Comment: Both the files4

Comment: comfig.xm,system.xml,admimhtml.html

Comment: I did change it and It is working well now. Thanks @AmitBera

Answer (score 0):

It Might be problem with your adminhtml.xml file . please look at two below code in config.xml we have code like this

`<helpers>
        <stockinfo>
            <class>Trimantra_Stockinfo_Helper</class>
        </stockinfo>
        </helpers>`

And in adminhtml.xml we have

`<stockinfo translate="title" module="stockinfo">`

Here module == means helper name so that is why we need to put stockinfo please check yours config.xml and adminhtml.xml